# How to make the Tumblr app read LaTeX

Tags: tumblr, latex

Is there any way to get the Tumblr app, for an Android device, to read LaTeX?

I have done a quick Google search which yielded no help, as well as scurried all of the options on the app itself. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: In what context do you want Tumblr to read LaTeX? On your webpage only? In users' feeds? I think the first is possible, I don't think the second is. I'd recommend using images of the output from LaTeX instead (optionally including the input if desired)

Comment: There are a few math bloggers who, like most mathematicians, write in LaTeX. The Tumblr app doesn't compile, and I'm forced to read the code. I can piece together the notation, however, it's annoying.

Comment: Web browsers are fine, just the app is giving me difficulty